# Get specific attribute of XmlNode

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

I have an XmlNode, and its OuterXml is the next code I have posted. I need to know how to get The name and the age for each Campaign.

```
XmlNode Response = client.GetNamesAndAges(xmlRequest);
```

```html
<Example>
  <FromDate>12-05-2016</FromDate>
  <ToDate>25-05-2016</ToDate>
  <Campaigns>
    <Campaign>
      <Name>A</Name>
      <age>2</age>
    </Campaign>
    <Campaign>
      <Name>B</Name>
      <age>1</age>
    </Campaign>
  </Campaigns>
  <Status></Status>
</Example>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath via `SelectNodes()` to get specific nodes/elements i.e `Campaign` elements in this case, and then print `Name` and `age` value from each `Campaign` :

```
var campaignList = Response.SelectNodes("Campaigns/Campaign");
foreach(XmlNode campaign in campaignList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(campaign["Name"].InnerText);
    Console.WriteLine(campaign["age"].InnerText);
}
```

BTW, `Name` and `age` are *elements*. *Attributes* in XML is used to reference something else i.e `bar` is the name of the attribute which value is `baz` in the following XML element `<foo bar="baz"/>`.

Comment: Be aware that if "Name" or "age" doesn't feature in a specific element it will throw an Exception. You might need to wrap `campaign["Name"].InnerText` and `campaign["age"].InnerText` in a method that would attempt to extract the information safely, if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var campaign = doc.Descendants("Campaign").Select(x => new
            {
                name = (string)x.Element("Name"),
                age = (int)x.Element("age")
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```